# win32ui breaks pyinstaller with --onefile option

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.8, win32ui

I'm trying to make an executable that uses the win32ui library but it doesn't seem to work with pyinstaller.
I made a test program to confirm that that's the library that's causing the problem.

```
import win32ui 
input()
```

If I use pyinstaller --onefile to compile the program it gives me errors during runtime. If I remove the win32ui import it works properly.
Compiling it in folder mode does generate a working file, but I'm not sure if it's actually working or if it's somehow importing the library from the system.
Is there a fix or a similar program I can try?

Comment: It works fine for me, using --onefile.  Please include the full traceback or error messages you are receiving.